# Ubuntu Core wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk not loading website

Tags: kiosk, mir

Hi I followed the instructions on https://mir-server.io/docs/make-a-secure-ubuntu-web-kiosk?_ga=2.83308050.546632768.1672447420-927150990.1672447420 and got up to the gray screen, however the wpe-webkit-mir-kisok doesn't display the website at all. Any recommendations on what I should try to debug this?

Comment: Same issue here on Ubuntu Desktop (22.04.1 and 20.04.5).
When switching to ubuntu-frame (fullscreen) I see the grey gradient but I can also see in the logs that the website was loaded. For some reason the website is not visible.

version: 2.38.2

daemon: true, debug: true, devmode: true, error-to-console: false, inspector-http-server-port: 8090, inspector-server-port: 8080, url: http://example.com

Answer (score 0):

Hey i had this same issue and found I had to make sure the snap was conencted to the correct display. i did the following

export WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland
sudo snap connect wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk:wayland

then rebooted

and that seemed to work for me